# Kernel GPIO functions incompatible between versions

Tags: linux-device-driver, gpio

I have a Linux device driver based on the [Derek Molloy book](https://www.derekmolloy.ie/kernel-gpio-programming-buttons-and-leds/).

It works on my Beagle Bone Black like a charm using a **Linux kernel v5.4**.

When I rebuild the same driver for a BBB with **Linux kernel v6.1** the build is successful but when I run the driver it doesn't work the GPIO functions seem ignored because button press are not detected and LEDs are not flashing.

```c
gpio_request();
gpio_direction_output();
gpio_export();
```

What is changed in Linux kernel v6.1 APIs for GPIO management?

Comment: Almost nothing changed between two except the graduatial dropping of the legacy GPIO APIs (the same you mentioned in your Q), as they are deprecated **for years** and subject to remove. You may consult with the Linux kernel Git history to see examples on how to convert your code to the GPIO descriptor APIs (mostly done by Linus Walleij). Ah, and you may inform the authors of the book, that they have to updated the examples there (like 10 years back or so, when GPIO descriptor APIs appeared in the kernel, much earlier than v5.4).

Comment: UPDATE
I found more info in the kernel documentation
https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/gpio/consumer.html

However I unable to figure out how should be written/converted that existing driver

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/linusw/linux-gpio.git/commit/?h=b4/descriptors-wireless&id=d09d091dd44c5d6deacc645a2291ef792b1d2b55, https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/linusw/linux-gpio.git/commit/?h=b4/descriptors-regulators&id=88034494b3290ab433d8325bb69158b4a921dd94, and so on...

Comment: Thank you @0andriy,
so the key is to start with devm_gpiod_get_optional() and replace the existing GPIO functions

Comment: Either that, or similar. It all depends on your (driver) needs.